# How to override virtual buttons and gestures (home and recent apps buttons) in android?

Tags: android, service, accessibility

I want to block home and recent apps buttons.
I was able to override physical buttons with the help of an accessibility service like this:

```
 @Override
public boolean onKeyEvent(KeyEvent event) {
    final String keyCode = KeyEvent.keyCodeToString(event.getKeyCode());
    if ( //home btn
            (KeyEvent.KEYCODE_HOME == event.getKeyCode() /*htc*/
                    || KeyEvent.KEYCODE_MENU == event.getKeyCode() /*xiaomi*/
                    || KeyEvent.KEYCODE_APP_SWITCH == event.getKeyCode() /*samsung*/

                    // recents btn
                    || KeyEvent.KEYCODE_APP_SWITCH == event.getKeyCode() /*samsung*/

                    /*Volume*/
                    || KeyEvent.KEYCODE_VOLUME_DOWN == event.getKeyCode()
                    || KeyEvent.KEYCODE_VOLUME_UP == event.getKeyCode())
    ) {
        return true;
    }
    return false;
}
```

but virtual buttons and android 10 gestures onKeyEvent() function not invoked and I can't override home and recent apps buttons.
I'm looking for a solution that really blocks and not a hacky solution like

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.REORDER_TASKS" />
```

and

```
    @Override
    protected void onPause() {
        super.onPause();

        ActivityManager activityManager = (ActivityManager) getApplicationContext()
                .getSystemService(Context.ACTIVITY_SERVICE);

        activityManager.moveTaskToFront(getTaskId(), 0);
}
```

Any suggestions?